# PHP intval lose accuracy with big decimal

Tags: php, integer-overflow

```
echo intval(hexdec('c0199506cb5dd57f')); // -4604485287595354112
```

When we did the same on the clients have another:

```
client on objective-c returns -4604485287595354753
client wrote on java returns  -4604485287595354753
```

I think it's because integer number becomes overflowed (PHP doesn't support signed integers) and in result loss accuracy.

How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

"The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is 9223372036854775807."

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Some workarounds would be storing the value in a string, or splitting it into multiple parts that can be put back together. Alternatively, there are external plugins for handling very large numbers.

Which solution is best depends on what the number is used for.

Comment: Alternatively, there are external plugins for handling very large numbers. Tell me please what plugins there are?